# Shortcut command for deleting cookies only for current page

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, microsoft-edge

I am looking for a command to delete cookies of the currently loaded page in Edge and also in Chrome. For now I only found `CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE` that shows settings menu where you can delete all the content for all the websites at once. I can delete cookies manually with F12 developer tool, but this is not suitable advice for the user. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Edge currently does not have such a shortcut command for deleting cookies of a specific site. For convenience, I suggest pressing this icon beside the address bar.[image: View site information]

Then, in the "Cookies" option, you can delete the cookies used for this site.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about that. Chrome has the same feature.

Comment: This is not a shortcut. If a native shortcut doesn't exist, an addon, a custom shortcut, etc., would most likely be a solution.